# Copy file from multiple sub-folder to another multiple sub-folder

Tags: batch-file

I have one parent folder and two sub folders and another 4 sub folder (2 in each sub-folders).

```
like a(Parent-folder)>>b(sub-folder) >>c(sub-folder) and d(sub-folder)
and a(Parent-folder)>> e(sub-folder)>>f(sub-folder) and g(sub-folder)
```

I am trying to move files from `c` folder to `d` folder and `f` folder to `g`.

Comment: Whatr have you tried so far? please share your code!

Comment: Please be more specific, Operative System? type of script? examples you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
import shutil
import os
 
 
def move_files(source_director, destination_director):
    # select the files in the source directory
    fisiere = [fisier for fisier in os.listdir(source_director) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source_director, fisier))]
    print(fisiere)
    # each file in the source directory is moved to the destination directory
    for fisier in fisiere:
        shutil.move(source_director + '\\' + fisier, destination_director)
 
def copy_files(source_director, destination_director):
    # select the files in the source directory
    fisiere = [fisier for fisier in os.listdir(source_director) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source_director, fisier))]
    print(fisiere)
    # each file in the source directory is copied to the destination directory
    for fisier in fisiere:
        shutil.copy(source_director + '\\' + fisier, destination_director)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
     # WARNING: paths to directories must be written with '\\' (double backslash)
     # here you set the DIN directory you want to move / copy the files

    source_director = 'c:\\Folder'
 
    destination_director = 'c:\\Folder\\Subfolder1\\Subfolder2'
 
    #CASE 1
    # move_files(source_director, destination_director)
 
    #CASE 2
    copy_files(source_director, destination_director)
```

THE SOURCE OF THIS CODE HERE:

https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/python-copy-or-moves-files-from-a-folder-to-another-folder.html